# R: comparing rows of values in two dataframes

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, one original and one that should be the original plus several additional columns of data after processing. I would like to make sure that the correspondence between original columns was preserved between dataframes (i.e., all subject identifiers still match up to the original vectors of data in each row.)

If original (orig) was dim 5000 x 50 and post-processing (pp) was 5000 x 100, and the first 50 columns that should be the same in each, how can I check? Is there something like setdiff() that can compare full dataframes?

```
SETDIFF <- setdiff(orig[,c(1:50)], pp[,c(1:50)])
```

Comment: How about `identical(orig[,1:50], pp[,1:50])`?

Comment: `all.equal(orig[,c(1:50)], pp[,c(1:50)])` as well

Comment: with all(), I got 'NA'. with identical(), I got 'FALSE'. How can I determine which are non-matching now?

Comment: Try `which(orig[,c(1:50)] != pp[,c(1:50)])` to get the row numbers that are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

In reply to comment above: to find the row and column indices where values are not equal, use `which(orig[,1:50] != pp[,1:50], arr.ind = TRUE)`.

Comment: Thank you. This appears to work as long as the dataframes are sorted in the same order. Is there a way to specify a sort order when running the comparison?

Comment: Prior to comparison, you can use `order` [ https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html ] to sort your data frames by any column or combination of columns that uniquely identifies a record.